# Reading numbers with AutoKey is slow

Tags: ubuntu, kde-plasma, autokey

i want get pressed number via AutoKey.
My Script works but is really slow and looks not very good.

May you know a faster way? I need hold down a key some seconds before its recognized.

```
import os, time, subprocess 
def popupNotify(text):
    subprocess.Popen(['notify-send', text])  # will be showed right top
pressed_key = 999999999999
for x in range(0, 150):
    retCode1 = keyboard.wait_for_keypress('<np_end>',modifiers=[],timeOut=0.01) # <== works
    retCode2 = keyboard.wait_for_keypress('<np_down>',modifiers=[],timeOut=0.01) # <== works
    retCode3 = keyboard.wait_for_keypress('<np_page_down>',modifiers=[],timeOut=0.01) # <== works
    retCode4 = keyboard.wait_for_keypress('<np_left>',modifiers=[],timeOut=0.001) # <== works
    #retCode5 = keyboard.wait_for_keypress('5',modifiers=[],timeOut=0.001) # <== works
    #retCode5 = keyboard.wait_for_keypress('<code84>',modifiers=[],timeOut=0.001) # <== not works, no error
    if retCode1:
        pressed_key = 1
    if retCode2:
        pressed_key = 2
    if retCode3:
        pressed_key = 3
    if retCode4:
        pressed_key = 4
    if pressed_key != 999999999999:
        break

popupNotify(str(pressed_key))
popupNotify("END END END END ")
```

#### I read here:

- https://autokey.github.io/lib.scripting-pysrc.html
- https://github.com/autokey/autokey
- and some places all over the web of course

#### System

```
AutoKey (Qt) 0.95.10
Python 3.8.5
Operating System: Kubuntu 20xx
KDE Plasma Version
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get input form the user using autokey, I think the best approach would be to open a dialog box:

```
import subprocess
a = dialog.input_dialog(title='Enter a value', message='Enter a value', default='')
subprocess.Popen(['notify-send', a.data])  # will be showed right top
```

Comment: Your answer works but stop each read with a dialog box. Can't say it's really faster.

Comment: Cool. Have you thought about using ``xev`` inside autokey to monitor the keypresses instead of using ``keyboard.wait_for_keypress()``? That might do the trick. If you want, I can elaborate a little better in another answer. Let me know.